# C linux shmget Invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, memory, shared

```
int shmCreate(int id, int size)
{
    int shmid
    key_t key;

    if ((key = ftok(".", id)) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((shmid = shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    return shmid;
}
```

I'm trying to write function which use `shmget`, where function gets size as parameter. I'm getting Invalid argument error all the time, except for size = 1. When I pass size other than 1 i got error, but the memory segment is created when i check ipcs -m, and it has size of 1. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: what is the value of `key`?, i.e. are you sure that `ftok` didn't fail?

Comment: 84008723, but does it make a difference? No, it is not failing

Comment: if it's `-1`, it would mean that `ftok` failed.  It's always smart to check calls for errors.

Comment: but, why are you using the `.` path as your filename with `ftok`.  Better to use a real file, not the current directory.

Comment: What is your code exactly.  I just used your code with a size of 25 and it worked fine.

Comment: POSIX [`shmget()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html) documents two scenarios for EINVAL: _[EINVAL]
    A shared memory segment is to be created and the value of size is less than the system-imposed minimum or greater than the system-imposed maximum_ and 
_[EINVAL]
    No shared memory segment is to be created and a shared memory segment exists for key but the size of the segment associated with it is less than size._  Have you investigated what the limits are in your kernel configuration? Have you created the segment of size 1 and now you can't grow it?

Comment: Note that shared memory segments persist independently of processes.  Process 1 can create it; process 2 can use it (and so can processes 3, 4, …), and process N can delete it.  Only shared memory segments that use the key `IPC_PRIVATE` vanish when no process is referencing it.

Comment: I edited my post, this is whole function, i use "." because it was a guideline in my assignment. When checking ipcs -lm, min size is 1 byte, max 4177919 kb.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what's the value of `id`.  I hope it's not zero.

Comment: This can't be your whole function because `int shmid` is missing a trailing semicolon.

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d33f856da9dc666a).

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page for shmget(2):

> EINVAL A segment for the given key exists, but size is greater than
>   the size of that segment.

You cannot attach a segment that already exists with a larger size. So you need to remove it first or use a different key.